# c# How to encode arabic characters to excel

Tags: c#, excel

i'm trying to export datagridview data to excel but may data in arabic 
and when export the data from the datagridview to excel and then when i open the excel the data i have stored is represented like this 
fTOCK_ID    ??? ??????  ????????    ?????   ???? ?????? ??????? ?????   ??????  ????????    ?????? ????? ?????  WarehouseID ????? ????????
1   ???? ?????? ??? ????    1000000000  28  ????    6000    10000   R-N ??????  0   1   1
2   ???? ?? ????    1000000001  5   ????    30000   40000   R-N ??????  0   1   2
3   ???? ???? ????? ????    1000000002  9   ????    19000   30000   R-N ??????  0   1   3

```
private void SaveExportedData(DataGridView DatGrdV, string filename)
        {
            string dataExport = "";
            string fColumnHeader = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < DatGrdV.Columns.Count; j++)
                fColumnHeader = fColumnHeader.ToString() + 
                Convert.ToString(DatGrdV.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";
            dataExport += fColumnHeader + "\r\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < DatGrdV.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                string stLine = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < DatGrdV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                    stLine = stLine.ToString() + 
                    Convert.ToString(DatGrdV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
                dataExport += stLine + "\r\n";
            }
            Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(??);
            byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(dataExport);
            FileStream FleSys = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
            BinaryWriter BinryWrtr = new BinaryWriter(FleSys);
            BinryWrtr.Write(output, 0, output.Length);
            BinryWrtr.Flush();
            BinryWrtr.Close();
            FleSys.Close();
        }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're creating a tab-delimited text file containing Arabic characters? I'm not sure using Code Page 864 is the right way to do it, see for example [this post on the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fba83600-7d45-46df-bbaa-21658f048676/a-problem-in-encoding-in-cp-864) - what happens when you just write the Arabic text?

Comment: Why don't you write it as an xlsx file?

Comment: i am writing it in xlsx file

Comment: @DevOsamaFY No, you are not. You are writing a tab-delimited file format. This is not the same as .xlsx files, which are actually a bundle of XML files (and others) inside a zip archive container.

Comment: pls just tell me how to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK Excel only understands tab-delimited and CSV files using US-ASCII and UTF8 encodings. Try replacing this:

```cs
Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(864);
byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(dataExport);
```

With:

```cs
Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(true); //Include Preamble/Byte Order Mark
byte[] output = utf8.GetBytes(dataExport);
```

== Complete Example ==

The following C# code writes a .txt file with Arabic characters, which Excel correctly renders **when using File > Open to read the file**. As I noted in comments, Excel's drag-and-drop handler is broken and does not honor file encodings.

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        const string TAB = "\t";
        public static string GetTabSeparatedValues()
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{2}\r\n", "English", TAB, "Arabic");
            builder.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{2}\r\n", "al-nahw al-wafy", TAB, "النحو الوافي");
            return builder.ToString();
        }

        public static void WriteToUTF8(string filename, string data)
        {
            Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(true); //Include Preamble/Byte Order Mark
            byte[] output = utf8.GetBytes(data.ToString());

            using (FileStream FleSys = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
            using (BinaryWriter BinryWrtr = new BinaryWriter(FleSys))
            {
                BinryWrtr.Write(output, 0, output.Length);
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = GetTabSeparatedValues();
            WriteToUTF8("Test.txt", data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: now the ?? replaced with this ƒØ±Ø³ÙŠ Ø¨Ù„Ø§Ø³ØªÙƒ Ø±Ø¬Ù„ Ø­Ø¯ÙŠØ¯

Comment: @DevOsamaFY Are you using File > Open in Excel? Excel's drag-and-drop handler does not respect encoded files.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning There is no text but encoded text. Any program that reads text must use the same character encoding that the writer used. As you allude to, Excel has a text import wizard that asks (but it calls it File Origin).